# cannot make third_party package rosgui_paramedit in groovy

Tags: rosmake, rqt, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to rosmake rosgui_paramedit package in groovy however some errors occurs. Following is the terminal output of procedure I make it.

```
adrian@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosdep install rosgui_paramedit
#All required rosdeps installed successfully

adrian@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosmake rosgui_paramedit
.
.
.
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgui_paramedit [ make ]                              
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linessgui_paramedit: 27.5 sec ]  [ 1 Active 36/37 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
  [rosbuild] Building package rosgui_paramedit
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/adrian/catkin_ws/src/rosgui_paramedit/build/devel
  -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/adrian/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
  -- This workspace overlays: /home/adrian/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
  -- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
  -- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE 
  -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
  -- catkin 0.5.63
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  -- Looking for Q_WS_X11
  -- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
  -- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
  -- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
  -- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
  -- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
  -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
  -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
  -- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.1", required is "4.6")
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:1145 (message):
    [rosbuild] Failed to include hide_plugin_symbols from pluginlib
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:44 (rosbuild_include)


   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
 [ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosgui_paramedit written to:
 [ rosmake ]    /home/adrian/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130226-145458/rosgui_paramedit/build_output.log
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgui_paramedit [FAIL] [ 27.62 seconds ]              
 [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosgui_paramedit. 
 [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
 [ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
 [ rosmake ] Built 37 packages with 1 failures.                                  
 [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
 [ rosmake ] /home/adrian/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130226-145458
```

Anyone know why it happened? Thanks in Advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56371/cannot-make-third_party-package-rosgui_paramedit-in-groovy/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without digging into the essential reason, in [its CMakeLists.txt](http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools/rosgui_paramedit/CMakeLists.txt), comment out these lines like below and `rosmake` again. Plugin seems to be working for me (Ubuntu Quantal), although I'm not aware of the effect so far.

```
#rosbuild_include(pluginlib hide_plugin_symbols)
#pluginlib_hide_plugin_symbols(rosgui_paramedit ParamEdit)
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-26**:
Thanks a lot !!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-03-01**:
These lines are essential to be able to unload a plugin when it is closed (else it stays in memory). The maintainer of the package should update the CMake lines to the current version of class_loader which has different macros for that functionality.